# Unable to install python pip on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

This is the command I used to install python-pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python-setuptools (>= 0.6c1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-dev-all (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already installed the latest version of python-dev

When i try to install python-setuptools using 
`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` I get the below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-setuptools : Depends: python-pkg-resources (= 3.3-1ubuntu1) but 3.3-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Explain me how to resolve the error and guide me the steps to get `python-pip` installed.

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get autoremove` , `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then install pip

Comment: Debugging Apt problems isn't a programming topic. You may be able to get better help at https://askubuntu.com/; but please realize that this is a FAQ there, so please search before asking. At least pay attention to the sort of details you need to include to properly diagnose the root cause (non-standard sources?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

got the same error when I install python-pip, the following command solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources=3.3-1ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Comment: Hi had simillar issue, and I want to ask you this command `sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources=3.3-1ubuntu1` meaning? because in my VPS if I ran this command will downgrade my `python-pkg-resources`

Answer (score 8):

download pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Then run the following (which may require administrator access):

```
python get-pip.py
```

This should get you going.
If you get stuck again, read here: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution that @seems recommended, I had to run this.

```
apt-get update
```

(OR)

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential 
sudo easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue, and eventually i gave up by using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

after tryings something like:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
```

but with no luck. 
So all i did then was to:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

peace of mind.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources=3.3-1ubuntu1
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

It will definitely solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jut run this command :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

than install python tools :

```
 sudo apt-get install python-pip
 sudo apt-get install python-dev
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

All the packages will get installed or some of them may say its already latest version, Thats fine